# Insert into SQL database, in foreach with checkbox list

Tags: c#, sql, foreach, sql-insert

I have this, and  made a scope identity on another insert that makes the int id variable

```
foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        int CheckId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO FarveTilCykel (fk_cy_id, fk_farve_id) VALUES (@cy, @farve)";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@farve", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CheckId;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    } //end if
} //end foreach
```

The problem is (I think) that, when it has run it 1 time and does second, the `@cy` is already declared, how can I make it different for each time?

Comment: create every time command new object as well in loop

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can't* add the same parameters to a command more than once. You can [`Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear) your parameters at the end of *every* iteration like;

```
foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
   ...
   ...
   cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

Or better, define your parameters before your foreach and *just* add/change their values inside of it.

```
var parameter1 = new SqlParameter("@cy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
var parameter2 = new SqlParameter("@farve", SqlDbType.VarChar);    
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
   ...
   ...
   cmd.Parameters["@cy"].Value = id;
   cmd.Parameters["@farve"].Value = CheckId;
}
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Answer (score 1):

place

```
var p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@cy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
var p2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@farve", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

before the foreach block and

```
p1.Value = id;
p2.Value = CheckId;
```

inside the block instead of the 2 current lines.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer open connection (conn) once and write it in using statement then clear parameters(cmd) for each record.